# How to identify Ubuntu VM is running on VMware on-premises cloud or VMware cloud in AWS?

Tags: vmware, cloud, aws

I need to Identify my Ubuntu VM is running on VMware on-premises cloud or VMware cloud in AWS (aws.amazon.com/vmware). I have root access to my Ubuntu VM. I do not have any access to VMware cloud or AWS cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dmidecode` to determine the technology

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89714/easy-way-to-determine-virtualization-technology for details

Then `traceroure` to determine location , assuming you know the network architecture on premises as you say, the Amazon vm will have a different gateway

Comment: I do not have info about network architecture of on-premises cloud.

Comment: Ask your sysadmin?

Comment: This option is not available.

Comment: Sounds suspect you have no system administrator you can contact. Amazon would give you network information direct